# Where is GitLab CI Pipeline looking for nuget?

Tags: nuget, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In my GitLab CI/CD pipeline, I use the `nuget` command to do a `pack`, `push`, etc. The pipeline runner is registered on a local machine. On that machine I downloaded the nuget.exe, set the first entry in the system env variables to be the path to it, and then added the source I am using via `nuget source add`. Locally, I can see the source has been added via `nuget source list`, however in the pipeline it is telling me the source does not exist. Doing a `nuget source list` in the pipeline job confirms the source I added isn't there.

My guess is it is using another nuget.exe, but I'm not sure where or why it would not use the system environment variable path first?

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe a couple things... First, double check that `PATH` is as expected and the locations on PATH are readable in the pipeline. The other thing is that the resulting config changes from the `nuget source add` command are **user scoped**. So, if you are not using the same user for your runner, you won't see those changes. Another issue might be if you're using a powershell executor, GitLab runs powershell scripts with `-NoProfile` which may also preclude use of those user-scoped nuget configurations. Maybe consider running `nuget source add` in the pipeline?